# Animisa Locana Pooja. Is it really what it is?

Tags: the-buddha, enlightenment

This is probably by far the most interesting theory that I have heard (Yes a theory or you may call it a story. I just don't have a reference to back this up!) about the life of Gautama Buddha.

The "Animisa Locana Pooja" was a act of gratitude. This is what I know and have been taught. Lord Buddha stared (wish I had a better word for this) without blinking at the Bo tree that gave him shelter during his enlightenment. But is it really the reason why he kept looking at this tree? For one whole week? I met this really interesting guy when I went on a pilgrimage that asked me these questions. And all I had to say was "Yeah he was being an example to us all by showing how to show gratitude".

Then the man asked "Son, Buddha is possibly the most perfect being we know, at least from a Buddhist's perspective. Couldn't he have been a better example by showing gratitude to his father perhaps right after enlightenment? Even as normal people whenever we achieve something the first person that we tell to are our parents. If you win the Nobel prize for literature would you rather show gratitude to your parents/teachers or your pen?"

I would be lying if I said I wasn't annoyed at this point. "Do you mean that as an insult?" I asked. He burst into laughter and said "Yes, but not an insult to Buddha but to the person who came up with the gratitude story. Son, he never showed gratitude to the tree. When Buddha attained enlightenment, at first, he felt that he had been liberated from all of the sorrows. But there was still doubt within himself as to whether he was actually a Buddha or just an Arahath. So he sat facing the tree. Using all his past lives experience and knowledge he looked at the tree and imagined that it was another Buddha and started a mental conversation with this imaginary Buddha to convince himself that he himself was a Buddha".

Honestly I was astonished! Was this man lying to me? To be honest I sort of do believe he is correct but I just could not ask him where or how he found this piece of information. What do you think? Is it what it is?

Answer (score 2):

"Animisa Locana Pooja" was indeed an act of gratitude to set an example to the world. It was also done to sanctify the tree as it would become the symbol of the Buddhahood.

The story your friend has told seems to be his own imagination. King Suddhodana was doing all he could to keep prince Siddhartha in lay life. So showing gratitude to him for aiding in the quest of attaining Buddhahood is out of the question. In any case, the Buddha later visited his father and saved him as well.

> But there was still doubt within himself as to whether he was actually
>   a Buddha
>   Blockquote

The Buddha is omniscient. He has no doubts and needs no 1 week long mental conversation with a tree to know something :)

Comment: Do you know a reference to "Animisa Locana Pooja" in Tripitaka?

Comment: I would look in the commentaries. Not the Tipitaka.

Comment: But my issue is whether attaining enlightenment happened suddenly in one day or even a moment. If enlightenment occurs in stages there can be a possibility of Buddha having certain doubts. King Suddhodana did keep the prince in the shadow but to chose a tree over a parent to show gratitude sets a wrong example when it comes to precedence right? If I show gratitude to my table/desk/book when I pass an exam rather that to the parents who said I am studying too much and go do a job, people would think I am nuts perhaps. I mean no insult in anyway and I thank you for you intellectual feedback.

Comment: Ah but your table, books, pens are provided to you by your parents. This is different. King Suddhodana was actively trying to prevent price Siddhartha from reaching the goal. 
Enlightenment happens in stages, but it can happen very quickly too. Read the story of the [Bahiya thero](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.1.10.than.html)

In any case, a Buddha is a Buddha. Once you become a Buddha, there's nothing more to attain and certainly no doubts

Comment: It won't look any better if I bought them myself eh? Has Buddha himself explained why he did the Animisa Locana?

Comment: Passing an exam is a trivial achievement compared to attaining Buddhahood. So no one would complain if you don't show special gratitude towards your table, pens and books. Besides the Bodhi tree provides shelter for life. It's a much greater service.

Comment: Well then one can argue why not show gratitude to the sun which gives life to the tree which is a far far more greater service.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. if we apply the same thinking, a student should show gratitude to the parents of his teacher, instead of the teacher himself

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille Lord Buddha got aid from trees and the sun simultaneously. Teacher and the parents is not a suitable analogy in this case

Comment: @Heisenberg Not really! The tree provided shelter from the Sun. Teacher/parents analogy is suitable as the argument was that the sun is a reason for the existence of the tree.

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille I partly agree and disagree. I just feel the Buddha could have attained enlightenment with or without the tree. For a being who conquered the mind what harm can some sun light do?

Comment: @Heisenberg It's not about the ability to attain a goal even under unpleasant situations. It's about showing gratitude to something that made life pleasant while you strive towards the goal. ex: if you are journeying somewhere and if someone offered you food when you are hungry, instead of thanking, do you belittle it by saying "I could've reached my destination with or without your food".  He hadn't conquered the mind until he became the Buddha. :)

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille Belittling a person is not the same as belittling an object. Thanks for the response though

Comment: @Heisenberg it's belittling nonetheless :) Enlightened being don't do that. Besides it's also about sanctifying the tree as a symbol of Buddhahood

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille showing gratitude to a an object implies a certain emotional connection to the object itself which doesn't make sense. Even I was brought up to believe the traditional definition but I have read nowhere where Buddha talks about sanctifying the bo tree. However, the  previous Buddhas have been associated with a list of different trees which were supposedly "sanctified" as a consequence of providing shelter. To go with this tradition a bo tree was chosen by the writers of the scriptures. It was that important Buddha would have said it himself

Comment: @Heisenberg "showing gratitude to a an object implies a certain emotional connection" - this is because you are thinking in terms of how a  non-enlightened person would feel :) It doesn't imply an emotional connection when it comes to enlightened beings.

"To go with this tradition a bo tree was chosen by the writers of the scriptures" - I have never heard this and find no issue in using the Bodhi tree as a symbol to represent the Buddha.
Haven't you heard of how the [Anandabodhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhi_Tree#To_Jetavana.2C_Sravasti) tree came to be?

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille It is not just a symbol. People do "Bodhi pooja" expecting good things to happen.

Comment: @Heisenberg "in order that people might make their offerings in the name of the Buddha when he was away on pilgrimage, he sanctioned the planting of a seed from the Bodhi tree". If you do that, it is good Karma for you. And it is possible to channel good Karma towards achieving something

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille It may apply for bo tree planted by himself. But how can it apply to all bodi trees growing in all places of the world?

Comment: @Heisenberg It was planted by venerable Ananda. Not all fig trees grown in the world are considered Bodhi trees. Usually the sanctified saplings of the descendants of the original Bodhi tree are considered as Bodhi trees